# How to split the layer id from url and join with comma

Tags: javascript

I have set of array of objects containing `url`, `name` and `address` where I want to get the `id` from `url` and join them by a comma.

```
let arrayOfObjects = [ 
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com' }
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com' }
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com' }
]
```

Also if there is "undefined" I want to pass it an empty.

Expected output:

```
001,002,
```

Here is my code

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [ 
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com' }
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com' }
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com' }
]

let urlId = arrayOfObjects.map(x=> x.url)
let getUrl = new URLSearchParams("?" + urlId?.url?.split("?")[1])
let dataId = getUrl.get('id')
     
console.log(dataId)
```

Comment: I would split each element of the array twice with `id=` take the second element and then with `&` and take the first element.

Comment: @Alvi15, Could you please help me with the code, Thanks

Comment: Your `urlId` is an array of URL's. You are treating it like a single string. Extract the query string parameter from inside of the `.map()` callback, so it returns an array of the parameters. Also no need to split by questionmark yourself. Just use `new URL(x.url).searchParams.get('id')`

Comment: @Ivar, Could you please help me with the code, Thanks

Comment: I would ask you to attempt what I suggested and then edit your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can map every element of the array to the parameter. You can use [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to easily get the [`searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) from a URL.

```js
let urlIds = arrayOfObjects.map(x => new URL(x.url).searchParams.get('id'));
```

Now `urlIds` is an array of the `id` query string parameters of every URL in the `arrayOfObjects` array.

Query string parameter values are always strings. There is no such thing as undefined there. If you want to treat "undefined" as empty, you could modify the `.map()` above, or just use a separate `.map()` do so. I find the latter to be cleaner.

```js
urlIds = urlIds.map(value => value === "undefined" ? "" : value);
```

Then finally, if you want them to be joined together separated by a comma, use the [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method. So the whole code would be:

```js
 let arrayOfObjects = [ 
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com' },
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com' },
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com' }
];

let urlIds = arrayOfObjects.map(x => new URL(x.url).searchParams.get('id'));
urlIds = urlIds.map(value => value === "undefined" ? "" : value);

let joinedUrlIds = urlIds.join(',');

console.log(joinedUrlIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using URLSearchParams not right take a look at the documentation:
https://medium.com/swlh/urlsearchparams-in-javascript-df524f705317

YOu first need to convert the url to actual URL objects:

```
let urlId = arrayOfObjects.map(x=> new URL(x.url))
```

Then you can get the params like so:

```
  urlId.forEach(u => console.log(new URLSearchParams(u).get('id')))
```

I also noticed you are using a Array as a string when trying to get the id.

Comment: You do not need to use new URLSearchParams since each url in your array has a url.searchParams. You can just do `let urlIds = arrayOfObjects.map(x=> new URL(x.url).searchParams.get('id')).filter(id => id);`

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a one-liner:

```
let theIDs = arrayOfObjects
 .map(x => new URLSearchParams(x.url.split('?')[1])
 .get('id'))
 .filter(x => x!=='undefined')
 .join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let arrayOfId = arrayOfObjects.map((obj) => {
        let url = obj.url;
        let id = url.split("=")[1];
        if(id.includes("&")){
            id = id.split("&")[0];
        }
        if (id == "undefined") {
            id = "";
        }
        return id;
    });
     
    console.log(arrayOfId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here check this out, it works fine.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [ 
        {url:'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=001&name=abc&address=1234@gmail.com'},
        {url:'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=002&name=xyz&address=5647@gmail.com'},
        {url:'http://localhost:3000/redApi?id=undefined&name=pqr&address=980@gmail.com'}
        ];
let urlId = arrayOfObjects.map((x)=>{ if ( !isNaN(Number(x.url.slice(x.url.indexOf("?")+4,
x.url.indexOf("?")+5))) )
{ return x.url.slice(x.url.indexOf("?")+4, x.url.indexOf("&"))  }
       else {return ""} 
});
       console.log(urlId)
```

But if you exactly wanted to use `URLSearchParams`, I can also do it with that